# Haskell: Format number with comma seperators

Tags: haskell

Is there a library function to put commas into numbers with Haskell?

I want a function that would work something like this:

```
format 1000000 = "1,000,000"
format 1045.31 = "1,045.31"
```

but I can't seem to find any number formatting functions of this type in Haskell. Where are the number formatting functions?

Comment: ++ For asking for a library and not an function.

Comment: This is probably related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388209/how-to-format-numbers-according-to-locale-in-haskell (how to format numbers according to locale)

Comment: If the library does not exist then you should use this as a great excuse to write your first Haskell Cabal Package.

Answer (score 10):

Perhaps you could use some of the functions from Data.Split:

http://hackage.haskell.org/cgi-bin/hackage-scripts/package/split

I know this isn't quite what you want, but you could use Data.List.intersperse

http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.1/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.0/Data-List.html#v:intersperse

**EDIT**: This does what you want, although I know you want a library function, this may be as close as you get (please excuse my poor coding style):

```
import Data.List.Split
import Data.List

format x = h++t
    where
        sp = break (== '.') $ show x
        h = reverse (intercalate "," $ splitEvery 3 $ reverse $ fst sp) 
        t = snd sp
```

Comment: This was actually my thinking as well.

Comment: For Floats, `show x` should be replaced with `showFFloat Nothing x ""` from `Numeric` package. Also, `splitEvery` is `chunksOf` now.

Answer (score 2):

Using the format-numbers library

```
Prelude> import Data.Text.Format.Numbers
Prelude Data.Text.Format.Numbers> prettyF (PrettyCfg 2 (Just ',') '.') 2132871293.3412
"2,132,871,293.34"
```

Answer (score 1):

(from hier: http://bluebones.net/2007/02/formatting-decimals-in-haskell/)

**Formatting Decimals in Haskell**

A formatting function to go from numbers like 333999333.33 to “333,999,999.33″ in Haskell. Copes with negative numbers and rounds to 2 dp (easy to add a paramater for that should you wish).

Examples:

*Main> formatDecimal 44

"44.00"

*Main> formatDecimal 94280943.4324

"94,280,943.43"

*Main> formatDecimal (-89438.329)

"-89,438.33"

```
import Data.Graph.Inductive.Query.Monad (mapFst)
import List
import Text.Printf

formatDecimal d
    | d < 0.0   = "-" ++ (formatPositiveDecimal (-d))
    | otherwise = formatPositiveDecimal d
    where formatPositiveDecimal = uncurry (++) . mapFst addCommas . span (/= '.') . printf "%0.2f"
          addCommas = reverse . concat . intersperse "," . unfoldr splitIntoBlocksOfThree . reverse
          splitIntoBlocksOfThree l = case splitAt 3 l of ([], _) -> Nothing; p-> Just p
```

Comment: Nice handling of negatives.  If you don't happen to have the fgl package installed, the base package includes `first` from Control.Arrow that can replace `mapFst`.  (Recent version of base have Data.Bifunctor, which defines a `first` that is usable in the same way.)

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem myself. My very pragmatic solution (using Text as T) is this:

```
T.replace (T.singleton '.') (T.singleton ',') $
T.pack $
showFixed False 42.0
```

Does not work for separators, though. That was fine with me.

For me Locale is not helpful unless there is a way to set it.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that I'm using:

```
thousands :: Double -> Text
thousands d = T.intercalate "." $ case T.splitOn "." (T.pack (show d)) of
    x:xs -> (T.pack . reverse . go . reverse . T.unpack) x : xs
    xs -> xs
  where
    go (x:y:z:[])    = x:y:z:[]
    go (x:y:z:['-']) = x:y:z:['-']
    go (x:y:z:xs)    = x:y:z:',':go xs
    go xs            = xs
```

Answer (score -2):

Check out the `Text.Printf` module in *base*:

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Text-Printf.html

Comment: I'm not sure this works for what is requested. This simply provides `printf`, but what implementation of `printf` supports regional numeric display with commas? What he wants is something like [Number::Format](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Number-Format/Format.pm) for perl.